# setInterval for the length of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set an interval for the length of an array in state.
The array `eventDate` has a length of 4, so the function should return 0, 1, 2, 3, then return to 0.
Here is what I have so far:

```js
const [eventDateIndex, setEventDateIndex] = useState(0);

const indexTimer = () => {
  setEventDateIndex(eventDateIndex + 1)
};

const time = eventDate[eventDateIndex]

useEffect(() => {
  if (eventDateIndex === eventDate.length) {
    setEventDateIndex(0)
  }

  console.log(eventDateIndex)
  const id = setInterval(indexTimer, 2000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);

}, [eventDateIndex]);
```

However, the console returns 0, 1, 2, 3, then returns 4 before returning to 0.
I know it has something to do with how indexTimer runs before useEffect, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Try using setTimeout recursion. It definitely sounds like your code is racing.

Comment: This has all kinds of problems like setting setInterval (a new interval) every time eventDateIndex changes. The code should be a lot simpler to achieve the same result - you want to recursively increment a counter every 2s for the length of the array?

Comment: @Dominic the eventDateIndex only sets once and shouldn't change. The reason I'm using it in useEffect is because I need to wait for eventDateIndex to set (although as I'm writing this I feel like I'm coding this really stupidly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only create an interval timer once:

```
function YourComponent({ eventDate }) {
  const tickId = useRef(null);
  const [eventIndex, setEventIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    tickId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setEventIndex(i => (i <= eventDate.length - 2 ? i + 1 : 0));
    }, 2000);

    // Clear interval if length changes or component unmounts
    return () => clearInterval(tickId.current);
  }, [setEventIndex, eventDate.length]);

  return (
    <div>Event date: {eventDate[eventIndex]}</div>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-moon-ejf6m

The extra complexity with `tickId` is to ensure that the old timer is removed if the array length changes.

Comment: Thousand thanks! I see that I was doing wrong. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Np, note I'm using the functional version of `setEventIndex` so I don't have to pass `eventIndex` in as a dependency (that way the effect will just get called on mount or if eventDate array length changes)

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are 0 based. YOu need to change

```
if (eventDateIndex === eventDate.length) {
    setEventDateIndex(0)
  }
```

to

```
if (eventDateIndex === eventDate.length - 1) {
    setEventDateIndex(0)
  }
```

Comment: I tried this before, it returns in console but there is no timeout for 3 - returns 3 then goes straight back to 0

Comment: I posted the answer to your above question as another answer. Please check and act accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function `eventDate.length`  returns the length of the array, so 4 in your example, but you want to go to 3, so this code :

```js
if (eventDateIndex === eventDate.length) {
    setEventDateIndex(0)
  }
```

May be written in that way :

```js
if ( eventDateIndex >= (eventDate.length - 1) ) {
    setEventDateIndex(0)
  }
```

Comment: Same this happens as the other answer - it returns in console but there is no timeout for 3. returns 3 then goes straight back to 0

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a small flaw in your code. Here is the working version of what you are trying to achieve.

```
const eventDate = ["12/21/2019", "12/20/2019", "12/31/2019"];
    const [eventDateIndex, setEventDateIndex] = useState(0);

    const indexTimer = () => {
        if (eventDateIndex != eventDate.length - 1) setEventDateIndex(eventDateIndex + 1);
        else setEventDateIndex(0);
    };

    const time = eventDate[eventDateIndex];

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(eventDateIndex);
        const id = setInterval(indexTimer, 2000);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, [eventDateIndex]);

    return null;
```

Comment: I like how you did this.  How would you recommend running `setInterval` in perpetuity? I threw a `if (eventDateIndex === eventDate.length -1) { setEventDateIndex(0) } ` in there and then used `else if (eventDateIndex != . . . ` rest of your `indexTimer()`.  I am incrementing `0 - array.length` to return a list of `.jpeg` files for a slideshow, so more simple... -- Update: Oh I am seeing you put `else setEventDateIndex(0)`, I must have missed that, but it's the first thing I tried on my own and it didn't work, needed "full" `.length if` statement first and `.length - 1` or didn't roll over.